# Should the speed of producer-consumer increase with more threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement a producer-consumer problem program in C++. One of the threads fills a queue with vectors of different numbers, while the other threads take the vectors out of the queue (synchronized using conditional variables/unique locks) and perform a simple for loop over the vector, doing some operations over the numbers. The problem is, the program's speed doesn't seem to be increasing if I use more than 2 threads. Here are some things I have found out working on it:

- The producer thread is faster than the consumers, meaning the vector will be filled way faster than the consumers are able to process the data
- Processing a single vector from the queue takes a very short time, meaning the consumers are constantly asking for data from the queue (I see this as a possible bottleneck due to the synchronization, but am not sure)

In such a program, is it expected that more threads would make the program faster, or is the constant speed independent of thread count?
Thanks for any answers or explanations!

Comment: How many cores does your CPU have? If you have 3-4 or less, you won't get more performance anyway.

Comment: Also, it does sound like your synchronization overhead is the limiting factor here. You can try to do batching (take more than one vector each time) or maybe have the producer thread assign work to a specific thread and reduce the lock contention.

Comment: Also be aware that std::vector touches the heap, which does it's own locking. Switching to constant length arrays might help if that's the problem. But you really need to profile to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. The CPU has 6 cores, so that shouldn't be the problem. I tried using a constant length array but it didn't amount to much. Batching does help improve the overall time, but doesn't change the fact that more than 2 cores don't make a difference at all...

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Amdahl's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

If your synchronization takes significant time compared to the computation, you cannot expect much speedup because the critical section is effectively single-threaded. Also memory allocation / deallocation is effectively single-threaded in your scenario because your producer allocates from its own memory arena and the consumers need to deallocate the vectors into the same arena.

A good way around this is to increase the size of the work items. Don't take single vectors but multiple ones. The exact size will need some benchmarking. A good starting point would be to take ca. L2 cache size, meaning vectors with an accumulative size of something around 64-256 kiB.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did increase the workload (a single thread took around 250 items at once), and while it did improve the overall speed of the program, it still doesn't change the fact that using more than 2 cores has no effect on the speed...

Comment: @icyfox It is possible that you are limited by memory bandwidth rather than compute performance. How big are individual vectors? How much data do you produce per second? What type of computation do you perform on them?